Failed to spawn child process ?/usr/local/libexec/webkit2gtk-4.1/WebKitNetworkProcess? (No such file or directory)
I removed the libwebkit2gtk files installed after compiling webkit, in order to use the repository library from scratch.
I re-installed libjavascriptcoregtk-4.1-dev and libwebkit2gtk-4.1-dev
raphy@raohy:~$ sudo apt-get reinstall libjavascriptcoregtk-4.1-dev 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/69,2 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 408954 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libjavascriptcoregtk-4.1-dev_2.46.4-0ubuntu0.24.04.1_amd64.deb    
...
Unpacking libjavascriptcoregtk-4.1-dev:amd64 (2.46.4-0ubuntu0.24.04.1) over    
(2.46.4-0ubuntu0.24.04.1) ...
Setting up libjavascriptcoregtk-4.1-dev:amd64 (2.46.4-0ubuntu0.24.04.1) ...



raphy@raohy:~$ sudo apt-get reinstall libwebkit2gtk-4.1-dev 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/286 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 408954 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libwebkit2gtk-4.1-dev_2.46.4-0ubuntu0.24.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libwebkit2gtk-4.1-dev (2.46.4-0ubuntu0.24.04.1) over     (2.46.4-0ubuntu0.24.04.1) ...

Setting up libwebkit2gtk-4.1-dev (2.46.4-0ubuntu0.24.04.1) ...

git cloned wxWidgets :
raphy@raohy:~$ git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/wxWidgets/ 
wxWidgets.git
Cloning into 'wxWidgets'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 905208, done.

configured :
raphy@raohy:~/wxWidgets$ mkdir build-gtk
raphy@raohy:~/wxWidgets$ cd build-gtk
raphy@raohy:~/wxWidgets/build-gtk$ ../configure --enable-debug --enable-webview --
enable-webviewwebkit
Configured wxWidgets 3.3.0 for `x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'

 Which GUI toolkit should wxWidgets use?                 GTK+ 3 with support for GTK+ 
printing libnotify
  Should wxWidgets be compiled into single library?       no
  Should wxWidgets be linked as a shared library?         yes
  Unicode encoding used by wxString?                      UTF-32
  What level of wxWidgets compatibility should be enabled?
                                   wxWidgets 3.0      no
                                   wxWidgets 3.2      yes
  Which libraries should wxWidgets use?
                                   jpeg               sys
                                   png                sys
                                   regex              sys
                                   tiff               sys
                                   lzma               no
                                   zlib               sys
                                   expat              sys
                                   libmspack          no
                                   sdl                no
                                   webview            yes (with backends: WebKit)

built and compiled:
raphy@raohy:~/wxWidgets/build-gtk$ make
/home/raphy/wxWidgets/build-gtk/bk-deps g++ -c -o 
webkit2_ext_webview_webkit2_extension.o -I/home/raphy/wxWidgets/build-gtk/lib/wx/
include/gtk3-unicode-3.3 -I../include -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/
 usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/
 include -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/
 usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/fribidi -I/usr/include/cairo 
 -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu 
-I/usr/include/webp -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/
at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi-2.0 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-
linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -pthread  -DWXUSINGDLL -DwxUSE_GUI=0 -fPIC -DPIC -pthread -
Wall -Wundef -Wunused-parameter -Wno-ctor-dtor-privacy -Woverloaded-virtual -g -O0 -I/
usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/
glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/
include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/fribidi -I/usr/include/cairo -I/
usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/
usr/include/webp -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0/unix-print -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/ 
include/gio-unix-2.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/
include/at-spi-2.0 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include 
-I/usr/include/libsecret-1 -I/usr/include/webkitgtk-4.1 -I/usr/include/libsoup-3.0 -I/
usr/include/sysprof-6 -I/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0 -I/usr/include/orc-0.4  -
fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden   ../src/gtk/    
webview_webkit2_extension.cpp

g++ -shared -fPIC -o webkit2_extu-3.3.0.so webkit2_ext_webview_webkit2_extension.o      
 -pthread  -lwebkit2gtk-4.1 -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lz -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lharfbuzz 
 -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lsoup-3.0 -Wl,--export-dynamic -
lgmodule-2.0 -pthread -lglib-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -ljavascriptcoregtk-4.1 -lgobject-2.0 -
lglib-2.0  -lz -lsecret-1 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lcurl -lm

 (if test -f utils/wxrc/Makefile ; then cd utils/wxrc && make all ; fi)

 make[1]: Entering directory '/home/raphy/wxWidgets/build-gtk/utils/wxrc'
 /home/raphy/wxWidgets/build-gtk/bk-deps g++ -c -o wxrc_wxrc.o -I/home/raphy/wxWidgets/   
build-gtk/lib/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-3.3 -I../../../include -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/
usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-
linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/
include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/fribidi -
 I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/
 include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/include/webp -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0 -I/usr/
 include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi-2.0 -I/usr/
 include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -pthread  -D__WXGTK__      
-I../../../utils/wxrc -DWXUSINGDLL -DwxUSE_GUI=0 -pthread -Wall -Wundef -Wunused-
parameter -Wno-ctor-dtor-privacy -Woverloaded-virtual -g -O0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -
I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/
x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/libmount -I/
usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/fribidi -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -
I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/include/webp -I/
 usr/include/gtk-3.0/unix-print -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0 -I/
usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi-2.0 -I/usr/
include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/
libsecret-1 -I/usr/include/webkitgtk-4.1 -I/usr/include/libsoup-3.0 -I/usr/include/
sysprof-6 -I/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0 -I/usr/include/orc-0.4  -fvisibility=hidden -
fvisibility-inlines-hidden   ../../../utils/wxrc/wxrc.cpp

 g++ -o wxrc wxrc_wxrc.o    -L/home/raphy/wxWidgets/build-gtk/lib -Wl,-rpath,/home/
raphy/wxWidgets/build-gtk/lib      -pthread  -lwx_baseu_xml-3.3 -lexpat -lwx_baseu-3.3       
-pthread   -Wl,--version-script,/home/raphy/wxWidgets/build-gtk/version-script -lz -
lsecret-1 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lcurl -lm -lpcre2-32   -lz -lsecret-1 -
lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lcurl -lm

make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/raphy/wxWidgets/build-gtk/utils/wxrc'

and installed
compiled the webview sample in build-gtk folder:
raphy@raohy:~/wxWidgets/build-gtk/samples/webview$ make
/home/raphy/wxWidgets/build-gtk/bk-deps g++ -c -o webview_webview.o -I/home/raphy/   
wxWidgets/build-gtk/lib/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-3.3 -I../../../include -
D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/
glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/
include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid 
-I/usr/include/fribidi -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/gdk-
pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/include/webp -I/usr/include/gio-
unix-2.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/at-
spi-2.0 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -pthread  
-D__WXGTK__      -I../../../samples/webview -DWXUSINGDLL -I../../../samples/

webview/../../samples -pthread -Wall -Wundef -Wunused-parameter -Wno-ctor-dtor-privacy 
-Woverloaded-virtual -g -O0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/
include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include 
-I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/
fribidi -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/
usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/include/webp -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0/unix-print -I/
usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/
at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi-2.0 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-
linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/libsecret-1 -I/usr/include/webkitgtk-4.1 -I/
usr/include/libsoup-3.0 -I/usr/include/sysprof-6 -I/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0 -I/usr/
include/orc-0.4  -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fPIC -DPIC   
../../../samples/webview/webview.cpp

g++ -o webview  webview_webview.o    -L/home/raphy/wxWidgets/build-gtk/lib -Wl,-rpath,/
home/raphy/wxWidgets/build-gtk/lib          -pthread  -lwx_gtk3u_webview-3.3 -
lwebkit2gtk-4.1 -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lz -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lharfbuzz -latk-1.0 -
lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lsoup-3.0 -Wl,--export-dynamic -lgmodule-2.0 -
pthread -lglib-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -ljavascriptcoregtk-4.1 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0  -
lwx_gtk3u_stc-3.3  -lwx_gtk3u_core-3.3  -lwx_baseu-3.3  -lwxscintilla-3.3 -
lwxlexilla-3.3 -lwebkit2gtk-4.1 -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lz -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -
lharfbuzz -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lsoup-3.0 -Wl,--export-
dynamic -lgmodule-2.0 -pthread -lglib-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -ljavascriptcoregtk-4.1 -
lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0         -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lz -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -
lharfbuzz -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -
lglib-2.0 -lX11 -lgthread-2.0 -pthread -lglib-2.0 -lXxf86vm -lSM -lxkbcommon -lgtk-3 -
lgdk-3 -lz -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lharfbuzz -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -    
lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lnotify -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 
-lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lXtst -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -
lharfbuzz -lfontconfig -lfreetype -lpng -lz -ljpeg -ltiff -ljbig    -pthread   -Wl,--
version-script,/home/raphy/wxWidgets/build-gtk/version-script -lz -lsecret-1 -lgio-2.0 
-lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lcurl -lm -lpcre2-32   -lz -lsecret-1 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0     -lglib-2.0 -lcurl -lm

Executing it gives this strange error:
raphy@raohy:~/wxWidgets/build-gtk/samples/webview$ ./webview

** (webview:91276): ERROR **: 19:05:19.595: Unable to spawn a new child process: Failed   
to spawn child process ?/usr/local/libexec/webkit2gtk-4.1/WebKitNetworkProcess? (No 
 such file or directory)
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)

For sure when removing the files installed when I compiled webkit2, I removed that requested file.
But I re-installed the Ubuntu repository's libjavascriptcoregtk-4.1-dev  and libwebkit2gtk-4.1-dev , and the configuration, building and compilation of wxWidgets didn't give any errors at all
Apart from removing, via ubuntu repository, and re-installing, via ubuntu repository libjavascriptcoregtk-4.1-dev, and libwebkit2gtk-4.1-dev, I do not know what I could do ...
Any ideas ?
